# Returing empty data array while getting the data from Node and MongoDB for API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, mongoose

I have the backend code as below

```
//Backend Code
router.get('/:producttype',async(req,res)=>{
  mongoose2.connect(dbUrl)
  try{
    let users = await equipementModel2.find({producttype: req.params.producttype})
    res.send({
      statusCode:200,
      users
    })
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error)
    res.send({statusCode:400,message:"Internal Server Error",error})
  }
})

//Front End code
function Allproducts() {
    let getproducts = async (producttype) => {
        
          let res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/users/${params.producttype}`)
          console.log(res)
          
          if (res.data.statusCode === 200) {
            setData(res.data.users)
          }
          else {
            alert(res.data.message)
          }
        }
      
        useEffect(() => {
          getproducts()
        }, [])
}

export default Allproducts
```

when used the front end code getting the empty array in the dom. I have tried with the front end code in axios but unable to get the complete data in DOM.
Taken the data from the database.
But remaining API are working fine.

Comment: Looks like useEffect needs [parameters.producttype] as dependency

Comment: Can you post the definition of the `params` object in the front-end?

Comment: i have just used let params = useParams() hook

Comment: I just wanted to get the api work dynamically according o the product type. For example I have selected one type the data related to that product type should only display.